# Output of -1L < 1U and -1L > UL is different when -1L, 1U and -1UL are symbolic constant than when they are declared as enum constant

Tags: c, enums, comparison, implicit-conversion, enumerator

B&R say in their book "The C Programming Language"- *Enumerations provide a convenient way to associate constant values with names, an alternative to `#define` with the advantage that the values can be generated for you.*

So I defined enum constants for -1L, 1U and 1UL. The result is not what I expected, it should have been the same in both cases.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define NEGATIVE_SIG_LONG -1L
#define UNSIG_INT 1U
#define UNSIG_LONG 1UL

main()
{
  enum { ENUM_NEGATIVE_SIG_LONG = -1L, ENUM_UNSIG_INT = 1U, ENUM_UNSIG_LONG = 1UL};                                                                                                                                 

  printf("-1L < 1U: %d\n", -1L < 1U); // outputs: 1
  printf("-1L > 1UL: %d\n\n", -1L > 1UL); // outputs: 1

  printf("-1L < 1U: %d\n", NEGATIVE_SIG_LONG < UNSIG_INT); // outputs: 1
  printf("-1L > 1UL: %d\n\n", NEGATIVE_SIG_LONG > UNSIG_LONG); // outputs: 1

  printf("-1L < 1U: %d\n", ENUM_NEGATIVE_SIG_LONG < ENUM_UNSIG_INT); // outputs: 1
  printf("-1L > 1UL: %d\n", ENUM_NEGATIVE_SIG_LONG > ENUM_UNSIG_LONG); // outputs: 0, expected 1

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler is giving warnings for the first four `printf()` statements: "negative integral constant converted to unsigned type". Also, aren't `enum`s of `int` type?

Comment: Compiler did not give similar warnings in my machine

Comment: Please turn up the warning level.

Comment: I have used option `-Wall`

Comment: Always compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C enumeration constants have the type `int`.

From the C Standard (6.4.4.3 Enumeration constants)

> 2 An identifier declared as an enumeration constant has type int

So in this call

```
printf("-1L < 1U: %d\n", ENUM_NEGATIVE_SIG_LONG < ENUM_UNSIG_INT); // outputs: 1
```

there is used the expression

```
-1 < 1
```

that yields to 1.

In this call

```
printf("-1L > 1UL: %d\n", ENUM_NEGATIVE_SIG_LONG > ENUM_UNSIG_LONG); // outputs: 0, expected 1
```

there is used the expression

```
-1 > 1
```

that yields `0`.

As for these calls

```
printf("-1L < 1U: %d\n", -1L < 1U); // outputs: 1
printf("-1L > 1UL: %d\n\n", -1L > 1UL); // outputs: 1
```

then it seems the type signed long can contain all values of the type unsigned int. So the expression

```
-1L < 1U
```

yields 1.

On the other hand, the type `signed long` is unable to contain all values of the type `unsigned long`. The common type will be `unsigned long`. So the expression `-1`L is converted to the type `unsigned long` and yields the maximum value of this type that is greater than `1UL`.

Pay attention to that the function main shall have the return type `int`.

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: How do I check the values `ENUM_NEGATIVE_SIG_LONG` and `ENUM_UNSIG_INT` when they are being implicitly converted and be alerted in such cases?

Comment: @HasloVardos It is a general situation with arithmetic conversions. You should take this into account.